# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.applepark.jni.EventReceiver.startCommEngine(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a EventReceiver.java file (in package com.applepark.jni) that calls a native method startCommEngine(String,int,String) compiled into library named "libevent.so". When the program starts it gives following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.applepark.jni.EventReceiver.startCommEngine(Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;)V
    at com.applepark.jni.EventReceiver.startCommEngine(Native Method)
    at com.applepark.jni.EventReceiver.start(EventReceiver.java:33)
    at com.applepark.jni.HelloJNI.main(HelloJNI.java:12)`

Following is my EventReceiver.java file:

```
package com.applepark.jni;

public class EventReceiver {

    static {
        String property = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.load(property+"/lib/libevent.so");
        System.out.println("Library 'libevent.so' load successful");
    }

    private String topic = "";
    private String host = "";
    private int port = 0;

    public EventReceiver() {
        this.topic = "/event/#";
        this.host = "192.168.7.116";
        this.port = 1883;
    }

    private native void startCommEngine(String ip, int port, String topic);

    public void start(String ip,int port, String topic) {
        startCommEngine(this.host,this.port,this.topic);
    }

    private native void stopCommEngine();

    public void stop(){
        stopCommEngine();
    }

    private native void publishData(String topic, byte[] data);

    public void publish(String topic, byte[] data){
        publishData(this.topic,data);
    }

}
```

This is the makefile that was used in compilation:

```
CLASS_PATH := ../bin/com/applepark/jni
IPATH = /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
CUST_IPATH = ../src/com/applepark/jni

vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : libevent.so

libevent.so : event_receiver.o
    gcc -m64 -Wl, -shared -o $@ $< -lmosquitto

event_receiver.o : nldcs_mqtt_comm.c event_receiver.c  com_applepark_jni_EventReceiver.c               
    gcc -I$(IPATH) -I$(CUST_IPATH) -m64 -c $< -o $@

com_applepark_jni_EventReceiver.h : EventReceiver.class
    javah -jni -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm event_receiver.o libevent.so
```

And here is my Native function implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "com_applepark_jni_EventReceiver.h"
#include "event_receiver.h"
#include "nldcs_mqtt_comm.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL    Java_com_applepark_jni_EventReceiver_startCommEngine
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject ctx, jstring host_str, jint port, jstring topic) {

    printf("startCommEngine : Initialising the Receiver \n");

}
```

Can't understand what is going on.

Comment: Your code looks for `libevent.so` in a subdirectory `lib` of the working directory.  As it in fact located there?  Does that copy in fact contain a definition of the required native function?

Comment: Also, your makefile has some characteristics that make it appear to be for an OS X system, but the standard extension for OS X shared libraries is `.dylib`, not `.so`.  I can't be sure that's wrong for your environment, but it's certainly fishy.

Comment: Moreover, object files intended for use in shared libraries may need to be compiled and linked with special options, such as `-fPIC`.

Comment: You got it right @John Bollinger I am using MacOSx platform to get this work. On other note, I was able to make Hello world JNI program run with .so extension compiled using makefile that is more or less similar to the one that is shared.

Comment: Is the native code in a C or C++ file?

Comment: It's in C @Wheezil You can look at the question for reference.

Comment: I suggest calling System.load or System.loadLibrary to diagnose whether libevent.so can be loaded explicitly rather than implicitly, and if so, if the link resolution is fixed.  If it cannot be loaded, you have a bad library, it is not where you think is it, missing dependencies, etc.  If it can be loaded and the problem goes away, you have a path issue.  If it can be loaded yet the problem persists -- well, that is the unhelpful outcome.

Comment: Well it wasn't the library loading issue. I fixed this by passing a structure (jobject) as an argument instead of (jstring,jint,jstring).